# Javascript recursive example

Tags: javascript, recursion

I recently had an interview where you had to recursively go over a string, and if it contained an `AB` || `BA` || `CD` || `DC`, it had to be deleted from the array. You would recursively go over this as deleting the `CD` from `ACDBB` would give you an `AB` which you would then have to delete to return a `B` as a string.

This is what I have, and when I test it out, I see it comes up with the right answer deep in the loops, but it never populates back to the top.

What am I missing?

```js
const LETTERS = [/AB/g, /BA/g, /CD/g, /DC/g];

const stringGame = (string) => {
    
    let newString = '';

    if(string.length <= 1) return string;


    LETTERS.forEach(regExToCheck => {
        if(string.match(regExToCheck)) {
            newString = string.replace(regExToCheck, '')
        }
        stringGame(newString);
    })

    return newString
}

// Expect answer: CAACC
console.log(stringGame('ABDCABCABAAABCCCD'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move the recursion,
2. `return` the recursion, and
3. Add an essential condition to end recursion:

```js
const LETTERS = [/AB/g, /BA/g, /CD/g, /DC/g];
const stringGame = (string) => {
  let newString = '';
  if (string.length <= 1) return string;

  LETTERS.forEach(regExToCheck => {
    if (string.match(regExToCheck)) {
      newString = string.replace(regExToCheck, '')
    }
  })

  // Moved, returned, and ended recursion
  return ('' === newString) ? string : stringGame(newString);
}

// Expect answer: CAACC
console.log(stringGame('ABDCABCABAAABCCCD'))
```

When recursing the function, i.e., when executing the function within itself, the `return`'ed value of that execution needs to be used, typically `return`'ed:

```
return stringGame(newString);
```

...in order for it to bubble back up the levels of recursion.

Also, since the `replace()` function is using a regex global replacement flag (`g`) all, for example, `AB`'s, are being replaced in a single execution, so there's no need to recurse within the `forEach()` loop:

```
LETTERS.forEach(regExToCheck => {
    if(string.match(regExToCheck)) {
        newString = string.replace(regExToCheck, '')
    }
    stringGame(newString); // <-- double oops
})
```

Rather, recurse *after* the loop, AND `return` the value of the execution:

```
LETTERS.forEach(regExToCheck => {
    if(string.match(regExToCheck)) {
        newString = string.replace(regExToCheck, '')
    }
})
return stringGame(newString);
```

One more principle of recursive functions is providing exit strategies—define what conditions to end the recursion, bubble back up, and return a final result.

The only exit condition provided is:

```
if (string.length <= 1) return string;
```

Surely if there's only one character left no match will be found—a proper time to end recursion. However, and more importantly, there also needs to be a path to exit when there are more than one characters but no matches can be found.

There are multiple ways to determine this but in the case provided in the question the most expedient is when after looping through the regex/replace routine no changes were made to the string. Since with every recursion the `stringGame()` function instantiates an empty string (`newString`) if, after looping through the regex/replace routine, `newString` is still an empty string, this indicates there were no matches found and it's time to end recursion:

```
if ( '' === newString ) {
  return string;
}
else { 
  return stringGame(newString);
}
```

...otherwise, recurse.

Answer (score 1):

The `stringGame` function doesn't have side effects, so the line in the loop here:

```
stringGame(newString);
```

doesn't do anything - you need to communicate the result of the recursive call back to the outer level.

A nicer way to approach this would be to combine the `LETTERS` into a single regular expression, and then to replace all matches with the empty string until the replacement produces no changes.

```js
const LETTERS = [/AB/g, /BA/g, /CD/g, /DC/g];
const pattern = new RegExp(
  LETTERS
    .map(re => {
      const str = String(re);
      return str.slice(1, str.length - 2);
    })
    .join('|'),
);

const stringGame = (string) => {
  const newString = string.replace(pattern, '');
  return newString === string
    ? string
    : stringGame(newString);
}

// Expect answer: CAACC
console.log(stringGame('ABDCABCABAAABCCCD'))
```

(If you want to use the global flag in the constructed pattern, you'll have to [account for the `.lastIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520853))